# Display value and number of duplicates in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database row named ID and it goes

```
ID
18464762
3936573
3936573
3936573
374749502
374749502
374749502
374749502
374749502
3746325
9705732
9705732
9705732
9705732
476870382
476870382
3746574
37264
37264
```

And I want to make a MySQL Query that displays the information in two columns, the ID, and how many occurrences of the ID exist. That way I can sort it by number of occurrences.

The ideal output would be

```
id           occurences
374749502         5
9705732           4
3936573           3
32764             2
476870382         2
18464762          1
3746325           1
3746574           1
```

This is just a small example as I have thousands of entries.

Everything I have already found from searching online tells me how to find which ids have duplicates, or the number of id's that have duplicates, but I have been unable to display the information like this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY` id, use aggregate function `COUNT` for counting occurences, and at the end order by second column.

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS occurences
FROM your_tab
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```